# Flex item exceeds its container

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a flex container with a defined `width`. Container has `flex-direction: row` and 2 columns. One is fixed width, it is inflexible. The other is flexible and should fit all container's remaining space.

When flexible column content is *long enough* it overflows the container, exceeds its width.

**Why** is that happening? And how should I fix it right way?

Note: I already solved it by using flex: 1 0 0 instead of 1 0 auto and it would be just fine. But I just don't understand **why it stops exceeding the parent** and why it starts wrapping the content? Is it even the **right** way to do it?

HTML:

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item inflexible">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item flexible">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
  </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: green;
}

.flex-item {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.inflexible {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.flexible {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

The [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8udf29b1/2/)

Comment: Romeno, Do you want to wrap the text to new line ?

Comment: that is expected , due to the fixed width of inflexible and no width defined in CSS , so it will not wrap and adjust the width according to content

Comment: TO avoid issue, define fixed width for flexible , .flexible {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  background-color: blue;
}

Comment: @NagaSaiA well I still don't get it clearly but I think if you answered I would  accepted it..)

Comment: posted it ..you can mark it as answered now :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To achieve expected result, specify the width for the .flexible class as well

```css
.flexible { 
    flex: 1 0 auto; 
    width: 200px;
    background-color: blue; 
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/LkJzLz

Comment: Any `width` value will do?

Comment: yes @Romeno, the word wraps from that width ....you can specify according to your layout

Comment: add word-wrap:break-word; as well to make sure it is working for all conditions

Comment: This works for me, but I have no idea what relation width has to content height being respected.

Comment: @samnau, if width is not specified , width of element becomes auto and content will overflow parent width and word wrap may not work as expected

Answer (score 12):

With `flex: 1 0 auto` in `.flexible` you set the following

1. `1` is `flex-grow` and its set to grow
2. `0` is `flex-shrink` so you set that to don't shrink
3. `auto` is `flex-basis` which in this case refers to `width` which is determined by the flex item's contents.

Also you can't use `display: block` in flex-container it doesn't work. Default value of flex-direction is row so you can remove that. You can set fixed width of `.inflexible` like this `flex: 0 0 100px;`. And for `.flexible` you can just use `flex: 1` and it will take rest of free width.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: green;
}
.flex-item {
  margin: 20px 0;
}
.inflexible {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
.flexible {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item inflexible">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus, cupiditate earum quos! Laborum quibusdam dolor temporibus corporis
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item flexible">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur modi sed ab voluptatum obcaecati repudiandae, quia architecto ipsa deserunt recusandae dolorum harum, aperiam sint, molestias iure voluptatem doloremque. In, rem.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is display value of children of inside flex block?

Comment: If you mean in `flex-container`, when you set `display: flex` on some element its children become `flex-items` and are displayed in flex layout model https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-item

Comment: So their `display` value becomes irrelevant?

Answer (score 2):

In http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-basis.asp it says the following about `flex-basis: auto`:

> The length is equal to the length of the flexible item. If the item has no length specified, the length will be according to its content

`flex-basis` is the third property set by the `flex` property shorthand.

So if you set it to `auto`, the `.flexible` div's maximum width (depending on its content) will be the width of the `display: flex` container.

Comment: Agree but I would have avoided the w3school reference

Answer (score 1):

I think you're misunderstanding one or two of the `flex` values here, if I understand you correctly. Consider the following codepen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NALvPw

Check this out:

```
.your-flex-item { /*(child, not container)*/
  flex: <flex-grow> <flex-shrink> <flex-basis>; 
}
```

Yours was:

```
.inflexible {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.flexible {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

If you prefer doing it this way, I suggest changing the `auto` value to your desired width, so more like this:

```
.inflexible {
  flex: 0 0 100px; /*auto changed to 100px*/
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.flexible {
  flex: 1 0 auto; /* 1 0 auto will grow to whatever 'auto' will allow it to grow to. Put in size here for it to grow 'up-to' that size. */
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: > /* 1 0 auto will grow to whatever 'auto' will allow it to grow to. Put in size here for it to grow 'up-to' that size.*/
Well...`flex-basis: auto` specifies `flex-basis` to use the `width` (`height` if `flex-direction: column`) of the block. Except if `width` is set to `auto` or *not defined* (that thing I was missing) in which case it orders the block to fit its content.

Comment: So any value of `flex-basis` should work except `auto` if `width` is not specified. If any `width` is specified `flex-basis: auto` will work too. Even `width: 0`

Answer (score 0):

The flex-wrap property is a sub-property of the Flexible Box Layout module.
It defines **whether the flex items are forced in a single line or can be flowed into multiple lines.**
The flex-wrap property accepts 3 different values:
nowrap (default): single-line which may cause the container to overflow
wrap: multi-lines, direction is defined by flex-direction
wrap-reverse: multi-lines, opposite to direction defined by flex-direction
SO
try to use flex-wrap to make the flex items in multiply lines.

Answer (score 0):

Add Overflow hidden to the `.flex-container` element and `flex 1` for `.flexible`

```
<pre>
    .flex-container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      width: 500px;
      background-color: green;
      overflow:hidden;
    }
    .flexible {
      flex: 1;
      background-color: blue;
    }
</pre>
```

Answer (score -1):

Update `flex: 1 0 auto;` to just `flex: 1` in **.flexible**. And remove flex: `flex: 0 0 auto;` from **.inflexible**.

To understand more about flexbox check https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/8udf29b1/4/).

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: green;
}
.flex-item {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
.inflexible {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
.flexible {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  background-color: blue;
}
.solution .flexible {
  flex: 1 0 0;
}
.question {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="question">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item inflexible">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus, cupiditate earum quos! Laborum quibusdam dolor temporibus corporis
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item flexible">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur modi sed ab voluptatum obcaecati repudiandae, quia architecto ipsa deserunt recusandae dolorum harum, aperiam sint, molestias iure voluptatem doloremque. In, rem.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="solution">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item inflexible">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus, cupiditate earum quos! Laborum quibusdam dolor temporibus corporis
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item flexible">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur modi sed ab voluptatum obcaecati repudiandae, quia architecto ipsa deserunt recusandae dolorum harum, aperiam sint, molestias iure voluptatem doloremque. In, rem.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I had read the guide before but didn't understand what was happening.